# How to remove week end times when subtracting (datetime) in MQL4

Tags: datetime, mql4

How to subtract **`datetime`**-s accurately, without including weekend times?

**Example:**

```
datetime gapOpenTime  = 2015.01.01 00:00;
datetime gapCloseTime = 2015.12.19 00:00;

int      diff         = gapCloseTime - gapOpenTime;
```

This `diff` includes also weekend times ( when the market is closed )

How to remove these unwanted times?

Answer (score 1):

One may use

```
datetime barTimes[]; 

ArrayCopySeries( barTimes, MODE_TIME, _Symbol, PERIOD_CURRENT ); // Time[] array was sorted in a descending order

int gapOpenSHIFT  = ArrayBsearch( barTimes, gapOpenTime,  WHOLE_ARRAY, 0, MODE_DESCEND );
int gapCloseSHIFT = ArrayBsearch( barTimes, gapCloseTime, WHOLE_ARRAY, 0, MODE_DESCEND );

int diff          = PeriodSeconds( PERIOD_CURRENT ) * ( gapOpenSHIFT - gapCloseSHIFT );
```

Comment: Can you please add sample input output examples to improve the answer.